# Zend framework2 Fatal error: Class 'Application\Controller\Zend\Log\Writer\Stream' not found

Tags: zend-framework2

I am a new user of zend framework - 2, I am trying to use Logger function for my website can any one help me with this problem.

Please help me out with loggin the IP and TIMESTAMP aswell.

I have added these code to my IndexController.php

```
use Zend\Log\Logger;
use Zend\Log\Writer\AbstractWriter;
use Zend\Log\Filter\FilterInterface;
use Zend\Log\Formatter\FormatterInterface;
use Zend\Log\Writer\Stream;
```

Then in my indexAction I am using

```
    $writer = new Zend\Log\Writer\Stream('php://output');
    $formatter = new Zend\Log\Formatter\Simple('%timestamp% %message%' . PHP_EOL);
    $writer->setFormatter($formatter);
    $logger = new Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info('Informational message');
```

But I am getting this error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Application\Controller\Zend\Log\Writer\Stream' not found
```

And if possible help me out with writing a seprate module to export all the database entry to excel.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try that

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream('php://output');
```

or

```
$writer = new Stream('php://output');
```

Answer (score 3):

You should know about [PHP:namespace](http://php.net/manual/de/language.namespaces.php)

Once you include classes via the `use`-statement, you only have to call the ClassName (CN) and not the Fully Qualified ClassName (FQCN)

With that being said:

```
$writer    = new Stream();
$formatter = new Simple();
$logger    = new Logger();
```

The alternative would be to not include the Classes via the `use`-statement and simply call the FQCNs

```
$writer    = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream();
$formatter = new \Zend\Log\Formatter\Simple();
$logger    = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
```

Take notice of the leading `\` backslash.

Comment: I tried this too, since simple logging in ZF2 is not simple. I used $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream('/tmp/test.log'), and $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger($writer). However, i got this error "Options must be an array or an object implementing \Traversable". Huh? ZF2 2.2.5.